# MySQL Running for nearly 80 Hours consuming too much memory

Tags: php, mysql, ssh, fopen

We've been trying to figure out what the problem is here, and can't seem to get it. I'm hoping that someone here can help. We have been having frequent crashes and as I monitor SSH using the top function, it is showing that the MySQL connection has been opened for over 80 hours and is consuming nearly 20% of our memory usage.

We have a lot of cron scripts that run, but I don't think we need to use the mysql_close function. Is this normal? How would I go about closing the connection? All of our cron scripts connect to the Database using the wordpress wp-config file. So the scripts will all say something like

```
require_once('wp-config.php'); 
..... your code ........
```

Since we have thousands of cron scripts, we've created it in such a way to fopen a whole bunch of them. fclose is not being used. Could that be a reason for keeping the MySQL connections open? The multi fopen script looks like this.

```
$subdomain_array = array('sub1','sub2','sub3','sub4','sub5','sub6','sub7','sub8');
$count_subdomains = count($subdomain_array);

for ($x=0;$x<$count_subdomains;$x++) {

$cron_root_folder1 = "http://".$subdomain_array[$x].".domain.com/myscripts/";
$next_file1 = $cron_root_folder1."file_name.php";
$handle = fopen($next_file1,"r");
echo "<h1>".$subdomain_array[$x]."</h1>";

    while ($buffer = fgets($handle)) {
        echo $buffer;
    }
echo "<br /><br />";
```

We have about 75 of these fopen scripts running at various times. If anyone can help, we would appreciate this SO much!

I should add that SSH is showing that I have 170 someodd processes sleeping. I'm guessing that mysql is one of those.

Comment: mysql process should be running constantly, along with apache if its a specific query issue debug with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` that will show you what's running and for how long

Comment: 80 hours is hardly long for a process to be running. i have a box with a yet-to-be-updated mysql and an uptime of 5 months. it uses 221MB of ram and is under a pretty decent load.

Comment: Our hosting provider told us that the mysql connection should be closing, so he said that we have issues in our coding that is keeping it open. I ran the show processlist in all of them and they are show a state of NULL. Should mysql constantly be open when running top in SSH? I can't figure out for the life of me why this is crashing (every 10 days or so). I've seen gradual increases in memory usage as the days go on until it finally crashes at any random time.

Comment: thousands of cron scripts, shared host?!? there's to much going on here to be able to give a sensible answer via a web forum

Comment: It's dedicated 4 cores 4gb of ram. I'm not sure upgrading will help much either as it continually just increases. Server load sometimes shoots up to 10 and then comes back down. I've seen it as high as 30 before but it's bc we had a corrupted DB. What I don't get is why mysql is constantly open when our hosting company is telling us that it should close. SSH shows that the cron scripts take no longer than 30 seconds to complete.